# Unable to export a tree in json for three.js

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I made a tree with the sapling addon almost like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8689). Then I exported it to json by means of addition from three.js, afterwards to display in WebGL. But only the foliage of a tree is for some reason displayed, and the tree trunk and branches are absent.
I looked at json the file, there are no records about a trunk. Though the tree represents combining of leaves and a trunk.
What are the proposals?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. Perhaps this answer helps someone: it was necessary to convert curves to meshes, for example, as shown
[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2919/23855).